# R - suppress output when using options function

Tags: r, output, jupyter-notebook

I am using R in jupyter notebook.

When I run the following command:

```
options(repr.plot.width=6, repr.plot.height=4)
```

I get the following output:

```
$repr.plot.width
6
$repr.plot.height
4
```

This doesn't happen in Rstudio, but it does in my jupyter workbook. Typically in this situation I've used invisible() but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how I can suppress the output?